# Lookup Query returning JSON instead of Relationship Field

Tags: soql, lookup

My SOQL Query is:

```
SELECT Account.Academic_Alliance_Manager__r.Name FROM Contact LIMIT 1
```

This is returning a string like the following

```
{ "attributes": { "type": "User", "url": "fillerurl" }, "Name": "fillername" }
```

Instead, I want my query to return only the value in the Name field from User, in this case fillername.

For reference, Account is a parent of Contact. `Academic_Alliance_Manager__c` is a field of type LookUp(User).

If anyone could help I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: what system/client/code is generating/issuing the SOQL query?

Comment: That's really just what SOQL relationship queries do via the API. SOQL does not offer SQL-like behavior in returning a flat table when cross-object relationships are included.

Comment: I am issuing the SOQL query from within UiPath Studio. I am using this connector: https://go.uipath.com/component/connector-for-salesforce-lightning-platform